# If Else Android (Else always activating)

Tags: android, if-statement

I have the following code in an AsyncTask.  name is either "item", "setMax" or a sentence like  "Creating Database (this is a one-time function)."

My problem comes when I pass "item" into the code the code increments by 1 but then it sets the message to be "item Please wait...".  I think it is because it should be If/Else If/Else in sequence but I am not sure.   Is there a more efficient way or should I define constants and use a switch statement?

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... name) {
    if (name[0].equals("item")) {
        mDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
    } if (name[0].equals("setMax")) {
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setMax(Integer.parseInt(name[1]));
    } else {
        mDialog.setMessage(name[0] + " Please wait...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks from your indentation that you are missing an `else`:

```
if (name[0].equals("item")) {
    ...
} else if (name[0].equals("setMax")) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i put else if inside else if and last else code was not run can u help me.

Answer (score 5):

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... name) {
    if (name[0].equals("item")) {
        mDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
    }else if (name[0].equals("setMax")) {
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setMax(Integer.parseInt(name[1]));
    } else {
        mDialog.setMessage(name[0] + " Please wait...");
    }
}
```

You were missing an else

Comment: Other guy beat you to it...but I uprated you still :)